# How to get non-zero values from sparse SciPy matrix?

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

How can I get the values of a sparse matrix?  For example:

```
x = sp.sparse.csr_matrix([[0,0,-1,1,0],[0,0,0,0,-1]])
print(x)

(0, 2)  -1
(0, 3)  1
(1, 4)  -1
```

I am just looking for the values of the data, i.e., `[-1, 1, 1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accessed through the `data` property:

```
x = sp.sparse.csr_matrix([[0,0,-1,1,0],[0,0,0,0,-1]])
print(x.data)

[-1  1 -1]
```